# Lync auto achieving correspondences in outlook "Conversation History" folder

Tags: macos, ms-office

I'm using Lync 2011 and I wish to set rule to auto send all my correspondences to "conversation History" folder in outlook for achieving.

Currently, all my correspondences are located locally under the following dir on XML format:
/Users//Documents/Microsoft User Data/Microsoft Lync History

I've tried to follow the following link: [Lync for Mac 2011 - Managed Preferences](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj945442(v=office.14).aspx)

According to this guide, I should have a plist file for all Lync configuration named /Library/Preferences/MicrosoftLyncRegistrationDB.plist , where i need to have a flag that tells Lync to auto-archive conversation in outlook.

However, i don't have this file, and it hasn't been created as part of the installation.

Perhaps I can get a sample of that file with the right flag to auto-store conversations. 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Funny as it may sound, but I was manage to solve the problem just by logging in from another computer in my organization that runs windows. after the outlooks synched with Lync, I disconnected from the windows station, and re-connected to my original mac station - and it worked !